# What is the difference between んだ/のだ being conjugated and it being added to the end of a verb or adjective?

Tags: grammar

I was reading Tae Kim and I came across two different ways of using んだ, one was to add it to a conjugated verb and the other was to conjugate the んだ itself. Would this affect the meaning of the sentence, or are these simply two different ways of saying the same thing.

For example does 学生なんじゃない and 学生じゃないんだ mean the same thing?

Comment: Related: [How does state-of-being + んだ differ from んだ + state-of-being](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77840/5010) / [Conjugated word + んだ vs nonconjugated word + conjugated んだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60788/5010) / [Explanatory の particle in question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25828/5010)